# Привязка JS-клиента к той же временной зоне что и сервера Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, extjs

Например в Mysql есть список организаций у которых указана локальная временная зона в зависимости от места расположения. Сейчас сервер работает подстраиваясь под локальную временную зону организации. Нужно что бы JS-клиент также работал в той же временной зоне, даже если клиент будет в другой.

У меня есть два варианта:

- нужно найти способ JS перевести в локальную временную зону организации также, как и серверную часть.
- устанавливать на стороне Rails не временную зону организации, а вычисленную временную зону (сдвиг) на основании временного сдвига браузера (можно передавать в функции логина на сервер) и организации.

Comment: Что подразумевается под работой JS в той же временной зоне? Вы-как то временем манипулируете?

Comment: @andreymal Например клиент находится в Лондоне,  а организация зарегистрирована в Москве. Соответственно время которое будет передаваться в запросе будет локальное +0 для клиента, а нужно чтобы было локальное для организации +3.

Comment: Откуда, куда, как и зачем вы передаёте время? У меня есть подозрение, что передавать его вообще не нужно.

Comment: @andreymal Допустим нам нужно посмотреть отчет где параметры отбора это время создания записей в таблице которое записывается в timestamp формате. С клиента он передается локальное, а на сервере берется по организации, поэтому нужно чтобы они совпадали для получения правильного результата отчета.

Comment: По-хорошему время событий, произошедших в прошлом, должно храниться строго в UTC независимо ни от каких временных зон. Я бы предложил отправлять с js в качестве времени строку вида «гггг-мм-дд чч:мм:сс» без явно указанной временной зоны, а сервер пусть сам переводит эту строку в временную зону организации, а потом в UTC, тогда js может вообще ничего не знать про зоны (но может кто-нибудь предложит что-нибудь получше)

Comment: Третий вариант, который скорее всего у вас уже используется, а вы и не в курсе: хранить всё в третьей таймзоне, UTC, конвертировать ввод от клиента в неё, а вывод для организации из UTC в местную для неё. Rails по умолчанию **уже** хранит в БД даты/время в UTC, но при получении в ORM преобразует их в "часовой пояс приложения", выставляемый глобально. Можно указать и там UTC, чтобы клиент сам разбирался, в какой таймзоне показать.

Comment: @D-side Да все записи Rails сохраняет в UTC и при вытягивание данных с базы конвертирует в часовую зону организации (что нам и нужно), но на клиенте выводит с учетом локальной зоны где находится клиент

Comment: @Gankster так что выводит-то? Клиент? Rails? Или что?

Comment: @D-side Если пользователь находиться в той же часовой зоне что и организация то время выводит правильно, но если он в другой часовой зоне, то на клиентской части время выводится в соответствии его часовой зоны, а нужно что бы часовой зоны организации.

Comment: @Gankster я понял, что это **видит пользователь**, но в какой части системы происходит преобразование? У вас в клиентском коде? Или ещё на сервере?

Comment: @D-side проблема в том что я не знаю где именно это делается. Делает ли это Rails или JS и когда именно. Я знаю только что при формировании ответа отправляется timezona организации.

Comment: @D-side и если она совпадает с клиентской то все выводится правильно, а если нет то подстраивается под клиента. Но где именно это проверяется я не знаю, что бы сделать какие то изминения

Comment: @Gankster ну, доступ к коду и работающему продукту только у вас, нам-то тем более знать неоткуда. Только направление для поиска подсказать могу, откройте в браузере инструменты разработчика и посмотрите на передаваемые по HTTP данные, в какой они таймзоне.

Comment: D-side проблема в том что это не я делаю в коде, у меня такое чувство что это делает браузер или js как то при рендеринге

Comment: @Gankster браузер делает то, что ему скажут. Что вы ему сказали, вы нам так и не рассказали (и я предполагаю что рассказать не можете, т. к. проект закрытый). Если это не логика написанная лично вами, то это логика, зашитая в библиотеки (см. их документацию) или в браузерные API (см. MDN). Мы ничего не можем сказать о коде, который никогда не видели.